# Deploy DB to SQL Azure Failure - Unable to connect to target

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am trying to move a local SQL Server 2014 Database to SQL Azure and I am having difficulties using the SSMS Deploy Database to SQL Azure Wizard.  Everything seems to be going fine as the process runs.  The various Results are all showing Green until it gets to Importing Database.  It also fails for Creating Deployment Plan and Initializing Deployment.  The Error messages seem to all be the same:

"Could Not Import Package"....."Unable to connect to target server"

I suspect that the problem is my inexperience with Azure and my lack of understanding re Azure Account and Database Logins/Users/Accounts.  I HAVE been able to create a database on the Azure SQL Server manually.  The Azure account is an email:  appadmin@xxx.com while the Database login is azsa. I CAN connect SSMS to that previously created db on the Azure server using azsa login.

When I setup the Deploy Wizard I provide the azsa login and it DOES connect. during the Wizard setup process.

So why can't it connect to that same target server during the deployment?

Any insight would be welcome.

Thanks very much!

DGP

Answer (score 3):

Well, I ended up purchasing Azure Support and creating a Ticket.  Azure support did contact me fairly quickly, was very helpful, and ultimately provided a solution to my problem.

First, it appears that I actually was using the SSMS Deploy to Azure Tool correctly.  The problem seems to be with the tool and this was (surprisingly) not pilot error.

The good news is that they have an alternate tool that is available for download and which was able to EASILY migrate my SQL Server db to a new Azure SQL database.

That tool is available at:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/prasanna/2015/04/13/migrating-sql-server-on-premise-db-to-sql-azure-using-sql-server-migration-wizard/

The blog author - Prasanna - was actually my Support contact (and may be the tool creator as well).  The blog has a very detailed set of instructions but I was also able to walk through it with him.  It worked the first time and my new Production db seems to be up and running in Azure.

So, if you experience similar issues with the SSMS tool, I would highly recommend using this approach.

DGP

Comment: DGP, I find this tool to be very reliable. It is also very fast when pushing large volumes of data as it effectively uses BCP by creating local text files. https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/

Comment: Just a heads up.. the above link is no longer active.. here's the updated link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595

Comment: Thanks for coming back to share this after you paid for support! I've been trying to migrate a few times now and always fails after a period. Going to give this a go.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a SQL2014 database. I restored it onto a local SQL2016 server, then tried the deployment to Azure from there. It all worked fine.